# jQuery - resizing image to fit div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have divs varying in height and width and wish for my images to be automatically resized to fill these divs 100%, and then of course centred.

At the moment my images are set to width 100% and then using the jQuery below centred, but this only works for images where the height are more than the div once resized.. how would I make it 100% for both height and width and center also.. completely filling the div (even if this means stretching the image)!

Thanks.

```
$('img.shelf-img').each(function(i, item) {
    var img_height = $(item).height();
    var top_margin = -(img_height / 2);
    $(item).css({
        'top': '50%',
        'margin-top': top_margin
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `img.shelf-img{ width: 100%; height: 100%; }`?

Comment: Have you tried the CSS property `background-size: cover;` ?

Comment: you have some logic that ties the picture to a div?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use CSS to set both the Width and Height of the image to 100% and the image will be automatically stretched to fill the containing div, without the need for jquery.

Also, you will not need to center the image as it will already be stretched to fill the div (centered with zero margins).

HTML:

```
<div id="containingDiv">
    <img src="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#containingDiv{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
#containingDiv img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

That way, if your users have javascript disabled, the image will still be stretched to fill the entire div width/height.

OR

The JQuery way (SHRINK/STRETCH TO FIT - INCLUDES WHITESPACE):

```
$('img.shelf-img').each(function(i, item) {
    var img_height = $(item).height();
    var div_height = $(item).parent().height();
    if(img_height<div_height){
        //IMAGE IS SHORTER THAN CONTAINER HEIGHT - CENTER IT VERTICALLY
        var newMargin = (div_height-img_height)/2+'px';
        $(item).css({'margin-top': newMargin });
    }else if(img_height>div_height){
        //IMAGE IS GREATER THAN CONTAINER HEIGHT - REDUCE HEIGHT TO CONTAINER MAX - SET WIDTH TO AUTO  
        $(item).css({'width': 'auto', 'height': '100%'});
        //CENTER IT HORIZONTALLY
        var img_width = $(item).width();
        var div_width = $(item).parent().width();
        var newMargin = (div_width-img_width)/2+'px';
        $(item).css({'margin-left': newMargin});
    }
});
```

The JQuery way - CROP TO FIT (NO WHITESPACE):

```
$('img.shelf-img').each(function(i, item) {
    var img_height = $(item).height();
    var div_height = $(item).parent().height();
    if(img_height<div_height){
        //INCREASE HEIGHT OF IMAGE TO MATCH CONTAINER
        $(item).css({'width': 'auto', 'height': div_height });
        //GET THE NEW WIDTH AFTER RESIZE
        var img_width = $(item).width();
        //GET THE PARENT WIDTH
        var div_width = $(item).parent().width();
        //GET THE NEW HORIZONTAL MARGIN
        var newMargin = (div_width-img_width)/2+'px';
        //SET THE NEW HORIZONTAL MARGIN (EXCESS IMAGE WIDTH IS CROPPED)
        $(item).css({'margin-left': newMargin });
    }else{
        //CENTER IT VERTICALLY (EXCESS IMAGE HEIGHT IS CROPPED)
        var newMargin = (div_height-img_height)/2+'px';
        $(item).css({'margin-top': newMargin});
    }
});
```

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X8czt/1/)

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot: From the OP's post `"... completely filling the div (even if this means stretching the image)!"`

Comment: No prob bob, wish OP's wouldn't vanish after asking questions though.  Would have liked to know if my suggestion helped.

Comment: Sorry.. I meant I wouldn't mind the image being stretched if the image was smaller than the div, I need to keep the aspect ratio. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JakeHills: Updated answer, adding jQuery, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @JakeHills Any luck?  The JQuery portion of the code assumes you still have width: 100% as the default image width.

Comment: @IIIOXIII Not quite.. it's all resizing and centering, but I'm getting borders either side of images. I'm sorry if I didn't explain myself well, but I wish the div to be completely covered by the image. Your code is very close so I will tinker myself, but if you do have some spare time please stick about. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @JakeHills Updated answer code, adding a crop routine which i believe is what you are after.

Comment: Thank you! That's perfect, thanks for your help today :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the image ratio, I would set `max-height` and `max-width` to 100%. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8Lst/) a sample to show how that works. That will effectively shrink images that are larger than the div, but it will keep the aspect ratio.

For images that are smaller than the div, you will have to scale up with JavaScript. The basic algorithm is like so:

1. Find the aspect ratio of the image (width / height)
2. Find the aspect ratio of the div (width / height)
3. If the image's aspect ratio is *less than* the div's, set the image's `height` to `100%`
4. If the image's aspect ratio is *greater than* the div's, set the image's `width` to `100%`
5. Whichever dimension is not set, set it to `auto`

Obviously, you could use this algorithm for scaling up or down, but if you can be guaranteed that your div will always be smaller than your image, you can use the simpler CSS solution.

It looks like you've got code to do centering, so I'll leave that to you.